# Regex para split() en javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

estoy intentando hacer un patrón que me separe un texto si encuentra uno de los siguientes caracteres: +, -, x, /, .

He intentado con el siguiente código pero no funciona, alguien me podría ayudar?

```js
var texto = "Hol+A q-ue txal e/st.as";
var separador = texto.split(/+|-|x|\//);
console.log(separador)
```

Comment: Hmm..no te faltan unos corchetes ahi? `[+|-|x|\/]`

Comment: Al poner los corchetes y las comillas me saca un array con el texto completo, no se divide ('[/+|-|x|\//]')

Comment: los símbolos `+` y `.` tienen significado especial en las expresiones regulares, podrías usar como expresión `\+|x|\-|\.|\/` (escapando los caracteres coflictivos) o usar corchetes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Efectivamente, el regex que estás usando no es el correcto. Debes usar el siguiente:

```
/[+x\-.\/]/
```

Te faltaban los corchetes para indicar el rango de caracteres a buscar, y dentro de los corchetes no es necesario usar `|`. También era innecesario escapar `/`, y sin embargo si lo era escapar `-`. Por último, te faltaba el `.` en tu expresión regular.

Snippet:

```js
var texto = "Hol+A q-ue txal e/st.as";
var separador = texto.split(/[+x\-./]/);
console.log(separador)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ha funcionado! Por algún casual sabrías como se haría para mostrar el carácter que se ha utilizado en cada división?

Comment: @VladT Eso no se puede hacer, a menos que escribas una regex para cada carácter y hagas varias pasadas. Piensa que el separador no tiene por qué ser un único carácter...

Comment: @VladT eso no está en tu pregunta, además tienes que especificar cómo mostrar ese caracter.